# Fix overflowed bottom when using SingleChildScrollView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, responsive-design

```
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(
              bottom: Radius.circular(25.0),
            ),
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 25.0,
                  left: 20.0,
                  right: 20.0,
                  bottom: 10.0,
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Consumer<SessionModel>(
                        builder: (context, session, child) {
                          if (session.user.isNotEmpty &&
                              session.user['is_admin']) {
                            return CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 25,
                              backgroundColor:
                                  const Color.fromARGB(64, 255, 255, 255),
                              child: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () => context
                                    .push('/update/${data["animal_id"]}'),
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.edit,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          } else {
                            return Container();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        children: [
                          const CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 60,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 57,
                              foregroundImage:
                                  AssetImage('assets/images/cow-example.png'),
                            ),
                          ),
                          if (!data['is_expired'])
                            Transform.translate(
                              offset: const Offset(35, -45),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 15.0,
                                height: 15.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    width: 1.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  // if cow is inside red, if outside green
                                  color: data['most_recent_out'] != null &&
                                          data['most_recent_out']
                                                  ['closed_at'] ==
                                              null
                                      ? const Color(0xff1abc9c)
                                      : const Color(0xffe74c3c),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 25,
                        backgroundColor:
                            const Color.fromARGB(64, 255, 255, 255),
                        child: data['is_expired']
                            // Animal is sold or this deceased, nothing to do
                            ? const Icon(
                                Icons.not_interested,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )
                            : _buildHandleOutButton(
                                data['most_recent_out'],
                              ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                _buildMostRecentOutLabel(data['most_recent_out']),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(170, 255, 255, 255),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0, bottom: 25.0),
                child: SegmentedButton<int>(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    iconColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white),
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                          return const Color(0xff1abc9c);
                        }
                        return const Color.fromARGB(28, 255, 255, 255);
                      },
                    ),
                    foregroundColor:
                        const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white),
                    textStyle: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                    side: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                      BorderSide(width: 0),
                    ),
                    shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  segments: const <ButtonSegment<int>>[
                    ButtonSegment<int>(
                        value: 1,
                        label: Text('Zdrava'),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.health_and_safety)),
                    ButtonSegment<int>(
                        value: 2,
                        label: Text('Bolesna'),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.vaccines)),
                    ButtonSegment<int>(
                        value: 3,
                        label: Text('Povrijeđena'),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.personal_injury)),
                  ],
                  selected: {data['health']},
                  showSelectedIcon: false,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5.0,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData((0xe0c8), fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        'Ime',
                        data['name']),
                    _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData(0xe3c5, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        'Pol',
                        data['sex'] == 1 ? 'muški' : 'ženski'),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData(0xf06bb, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        'Starost',
                        "$oldMonths mj."),
                    if (data['passport'] != null)
                      _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData(0xe1f2, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        'Pasoš',
                        data['passport'],
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData(0xe4f5, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        'Tag',
                        data['tag']),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    _buildInfoPair(
                      const IconData(0xe038, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                      'Dodato',
                      formatter.format(
                        DateTime.parse(data['created_at']).toLocal(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    if (data['is_expired'])
                      _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData(0xe570, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        'Prodato',
                        formatter.format(
                          DateTime.parse(data['expired_at']).toLocal(),
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildInfoPair(IconData icon, String key, String value) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 2.0,
          horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02,
        ),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 2,
          color: Colors.white,
          surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
          child: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 15.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        right: 15.0,
                      ),
                      child: Icon(
                        icon,
                        color: const Color(0xff1abc9c),
                        size: 30.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      key,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 19.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 2.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      value,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 90, 90, 90),
                        fontSize: 12.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

I want to make the black box fixed and the white box to be scrollable. I tried to wrap the Column in which is all content from below with Singlechildscrollview, but it doesn't solve the problem. I also tried all combinations that I found on the Internet (added container to Column, replace Column with Stack...), but nothing helps. Do you have some solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Your Problem is that your outer Column provides "unbound constraints" to its children so that they may size themselves as big as they want. But a SingleChildScrollView needs to have a fixed size so that its own child can be scrollable in its viewport. So either wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` inside of a `SizedBox` to give it a fixed size, or you can wrap it with a `Flexible`, or `Expanded` widget to give it a fraction of the available free space of the column **after laying out all fixed position non-flexible children**.

The following contains your slightly modified code so that it can be run everywhere without your state variables and data, etc (just make sure not to directly copy it):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget _buildInfoPair(IconData icon, String key, String value, BuildContext context) {
  return Expanded(
    flex: 1,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 2.0,
        horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02,
      ),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 2,
        color: Colors.white,
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 15.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 15.0,
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      icon,
                      color: const Color(0xff1abc9c),
                      size: 30.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    key,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 19.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 2.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    value,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 90, 90, 90),
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: [
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(
            bottom: Radius.circular(25.0),
          ),
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 25.0,
                left: 20.0,
                right: 20.0,
                bottom: 10.0,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        const CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 60,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 57,
                            foregroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/cow-example.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        if (true)
                          Transform.translate(
                            offset: const Offset(35, -45),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 15.0,
                              height: 15.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  width: 1.0,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                // if cow is inside red, if outside green
                                color: const Color(0xff1abc9c),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 25,
                      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(64, 255, 255, 255),
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.not_interested,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "_buildMostRecentOutLabel",
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(170, 255, 255, 255),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                fontSize: 12.0,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0, bottom: 25.0),
              child: SegmentedButton<int>(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  iconColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white),
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                      if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                        return const Color(0xff1abc9c);
                      }
                      return const Color.fromARGB(28, 255, 255, 255);
                    },
                  ),
                  foregroundColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white),
                  textStyle: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  ),
                  side: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                    BorderSide(width: 0),
                  ),
                  shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                segments: const <ButtonSegment<int>>[
                  ButtonSegment<int>(value: 1, label: Text('Zdrava'), icon: Icon(Icons.health_and_safety)),
                  ButtonSegment<int>(value: 2, label: Text('Bolesna'), icon: Icon(Icons.vaccines)),
                  ButtonSegment<int>(value: 3, label: Text('Povrijeđena'), icon: Icon(Icons.personal_injury)),
                ],
                selected: {1},
                showSelectedIcon: false,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 5.0,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData((0xe0c8), fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'), 'Ime', "data['name']", context),
                    _buildInfoPair(const IconData(0xe3c5, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'), 'Pol', "muški", context),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData(0xf06bb, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'), 'Starost', "oldMonths mj.", context),
                    if (true)
                      _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData(0xe1f2, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        'Pasoš',
                        "data['passport']",
                        context,
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    _buildInfoPair(const IconData(0xe4f5, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'), 'Tag', "data['tag']", context),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    _buildInfoPair(
                      const IconData(0xe038, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                      'Dodato',
                      "created_at",
                      context,
                    ),
                    if (true)
                      _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData(0xe570, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        'Prodato',
                        "expired_at",
                        context,
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(body: Builder(builder: (context) => _build(context))),
  ));
}
```

Also i always recommend working with more helper methods, or even better working with more custom widgets for the separate sections of your widget tree(better performance than helper methods).

The bigger the build method, the more confusing it can get.

Comment: I just tried it, but as I showed in the comment above, it doesn't work, it just shows white screen without any content: https://prnt.sc/NJIDCBOtuybH

Comment: How does your widget structure look at the outside of this widget (where you use it)? Do you have it nested as a child inside of another ListView, or Column?

Comment: Yes Niko, it has Container as a sibling (this fixed black piece above) and Column which is the parent of that Container and Singlechildscrollview.

Comment: To clarify, The `SingleChildScrollView` is the topmost parent? If that's true, then that's your issue. You can't nest two `SingleChildScrollView`s. 

Either way, the issue isn't within the code you've provided, since @Niko's solution works just fine.

Comment: Yes, as @Sub 6 Resources said, your top most `SingleChildScrollView` would again provide unbound constraints to now the "inner" `Column` from the widget of the code snippet above and so that column would always have to expand to the sum of its children size. But again if you use the `Expanded` widget as a wrapper for the inner `SingleChildScrollView` it tries to size it to a fraction of the available space which is not possible in a scrollable viewport with unlimited size.

Comment: https://pastecode.io/s/6yvqvua3
This is the whole code of the component.

Comment: @GamerXxX you need to move the `Expanded` outside the `SingleChildScrollView` in `_buildAnimalProfile`. `Expanded` is only valid as the child of a `Row` or `Column`.

Answer (score 1):

The `SingleChildScrollView` you are using doesn't have any sort of constraint on its height, so it doesn't think it needs to enable scrolling. It's your main `Column` that is actually overflowing. To fix this, you'll need to wrap the `Padding` of the `SingleChildScrollView` in an `Expanded` widget, to tell that part of the content to fill the remaining vertical space. You also need to move the `SizedBox(height: 5.0)` into the inner `Column`.

Here's your code rewritten as I described:

```dart
return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(
              bottom: Radius.circular(25.0),
            ),
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 25.0,
                  left: 20.0,
                  right: 20.0,
                  bottom: 10.0,
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Consumer<SessionModel>(
                        builder: (context, session, child) {
                          if (session.user.isNotEmpty &&
                              session.user['is_admin']) {
                            return CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 25,
                              backgroundColor:
                                  const Color.fromARGB(64, 255, 255, 255),
                              child: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () => context
                                    .push('/update/${data["animal_id"]}'),
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.edit,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          } else {
                            return Container();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        children: [
                          const CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 60,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 57,
                              foregroundImage:
                                  AssetImage('assets/images/cow-example.png'),
                            ),
                          ),
                          if (!data['is_expired'])
                            Transform.translate(
                              offset: const Offset(35, -45),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 15.0,
                                height: 15.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    width: 1.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  // if cow is inside red, if outside green
                                  color: data['most_recent_out'] != null &&
                                          data['most_recent_out']
                                                  ['closed_at'] ==
                                              null
                                      ? const Color(0xff1abc9c)
                                      : const Color(0xffe74c3c),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 25,
                        backgroundColor:
                            const Color.fromARGB(64, 255, 255, 255),
                        child: data['is_expired']
                            // Animal is sold or this deceased, nothing to do
                            ? const Icon(
                                Icons.not_interested,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )
                            : _buildHandleOutButton(
                                data['most_recent_out'],
                              ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                _buildMostRecentOutLabel(data['most_recent_out']),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(170, 255, 255, 255),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0, bottom: 25.0),
                child: SegmentedButton<int>(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    iconColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white),
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                          return const Color(0xff1abc9c);
                        }
                        return const Color.fromARGB(28, 255, 255, 255);
                      },
                    ),
                    foregroundColor:
                        const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white),
                    textStyle: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                    side: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                      BorderSide(width: 0),
                    ),
                    shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  segments: const <ButtonSegment<int>>[
                    ButtonSegment<int>(
                        value: 1,
                        label: Text('Zdrava'),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.health_and_safety)),
                    ButtonSegment<int>(
                        value: 2,
                        label: Text('Bolesna'),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.vaccines)),
                    ButtonSegment<int>(
                        value: 3,
                        label: Text('Povrijeđena'),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.personal_injury)),
                  ],
                  selected: {data['health']},
                  showSelectedIcon: false,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded( // <---------------------------- Added this
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
            ),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox( // <-- Moved this from outside the scroll view to inside.
                    height: 5.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData((0xe0c8), fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        'Ime',
                        data['name']),
                      _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData(0xe3c5, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        'Pol',
                        data['sex'] == 1 ? 'muški' : 'ženski'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData(0xf06bb, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        'Starost',
                        "$oldMonths mj."),
                      if (data['passport'] != null)
                        _buildInfoPair(
                          const IconData(0xe1f2, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                          'Pasoš',
                          data['passport'],
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData(0xe4f5, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        'Tag',
                        data['tag']),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      _buildInfoPair(
                        const IconData(0xe038, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                        'Dodato',
                        formatter.format(
                          DateTime.parse(data['created_at']).toLocal(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      if (data['is_expired'])
                        _buildInfoPair(
                          const IconData(0xe570, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                          'Prodato',
                          formatter.format(
                            DateTime.parse(data['expired_at']).toLocal(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildInfoPair(IconData icon, String key, String value) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 2.0,
          horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02,
        ),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 2,
          color: Colors.white,
          surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
          child: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 15.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        right: 15.0,
                      ),
                      child: Icon(
                        icon,
                        color: const Color(0xff1abc9c),
                        size: 30.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      key,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 19.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 2.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      value,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 90, 90, 90),
                        fontSize: 12.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: This is correct. Similar to my answer, but you were faster. Just one small thing: why did you recommend him to move the `SizedBox` inside of his scroll view? I Interpreted his intention as it being a spacer, or padding between the scrollable content and the other widgets.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work: https://prnt.sc/NJIDCBOtuybH
I see this error in the terminal: Another exception was thrown: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: When I add SizedBox as the parent of this Expanded element and write some fixed height (I tried 300) to it, it will show all elements and it will work. But of course, this is not what I want because on some devices it will overflow, and on some, it will be too small. Of course, this is not the goal, just checked what would happen.

Comment: @Niko, I suppose my interpretation of the `SizedBox` could be incorrect. I assumed he wanted some space between the top of the scrollable content and the inner top border of the scroll area, so that when the user hasn't scrolled, there's a little bit of space between the content and the top container, but if they scroll, the content appears to scroll underneath the top container.

Comment: I mean it could also be the case. Only @GamerXxX himself knows his desired behaviour.

Comment: I pasted the whole code of the component here: https://pastecode.io/s/6yvqvua3
Now it looks like this, I tried every combination which make sense to me, but it doesn't work in any of those tried combinations.